# What does measure $0$ mean visually in the context of Sard's Theorem?

Tags: analysis, differential-topology

In his book *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*, Michael Spivak talks about Sard's Theorem.

> Sard's Theorem: If $f:M\to N$ is a $C^1$ map between $n$-manifolds, and $M$ has at most countably many components, then the critical values of $f$ form a set of measure $0$ in $N$.

Given that I don't have a ton of background in measure theory, I have been trying to wrap my head around picturing this geometrically (if this is even possible).  What is Sard's Theorem describing geometrically in this case, since this is in the context of manifolds?

Usually Spivak gives drawings for his theorems so that one can also have some visual intuition for what's going on, but he didn't provide one for Sard's so I thought I would ask here. Thanks for the help, and sorry if this is a really stupid question.

Comment: Think of $N$ as a surface in $\mathbb{R}^N$. A natural measure on $N$ is the surface measure, often written $dS$. It defines "surface area". A lower dimensional submanifold of $N$ has $0$ measure.

Comment: Think of what happens in dimension $1$ : you have a function, let's say, from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Consider all the points where $f'(x)=0$, and see them on the $y-$axis. Sard's theorem says that the set of the given points on the $y-$axis has measure $0$ (which is quite clear visually).

Comment: Measures on the manifold could be understood as usual notion in real space, since the manifold, or surface is locally Euclidean. So, it means roughly, we could cover such set of critical points by small enough open covers.(This is just what we do in the measure theory.)